# How would I get my character image to change when there is a jump?

Tags: swift, animation

I have this code where it animates my 2d character to make it look like its running. In my touchesBegan I have this code where when theres a tap the character jumps and I want the image to change to this jump image I have for the character. Why when I tap the screen and the character jumps the image doesn't change? Thanks! Heres the code I have?

```
    func addHero() {

    let heroTextureOne = SKTexture(imageNamed: "heroup")
    let heroTextureTwo = SKTexture(imageNamed: "herodown")

    let anim = SKAction.animateWithTextures([heroTextureOne, heroTextureTwo], timePerFrame: 0.2)
    let run = SKAction.repeatActionForever(anim)

    theHero = SKSpriteNode(texture: heroTextureTwo)
    theHero.runAction(run)


    theHero.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: theHero.size)
    theHero.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true

    theHero.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 3, self.size.height / 1.0)
    theHero.zPosition = 15
    addChild(theHero)






}



    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    var touch: UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch
    var location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

   if (theHero.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 250)) != nil) {
    theHero.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "jumphero")
    }
```

Comment: try to take that if out, just apply an impulse on one line, and change the texture on another

Answer (score 0):

have you tried not using the if statement? I'm not sure that your statement is returning true, therefore not going into the block, try this, without if. Just apply impulse, then change texture:

```
theHero.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 250))
theHero.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "jumphero")
```

Comment: are you sure you have an image named "jumphero" somewhere in your project?

Comment: no, I just tried to do the same thing in Xcode and it worked for me, same exact code (different image obviously)

Comment: what did you declare theHero variable as?

Comment: The animation for the running keeps going even when I tap on the screen. I think it has something to do with that.